# JavaScript - determine whether mathematic function is infinite

Tags: javascript, function, math

I am programming a web application to draw charts of given mathematic function and want to determine whether it has an infinite number of solution for Y axis.

So let's say I have a function like this:

**y = sin(x)*x**

When drawing a chart, X value is moving, so what I get is a graphical representation of a given function within chart area.

But I want to determine whether the function continues to infinity or not.

Is there any way to do it?

I know that it's possible by calculating a limit to infinity of that function, yet I haven't found anything relevant about calculating it using any programming language on the internet.

Comment: Search for horizontal asymptote calculators

Comment: Your function is bounded by `y = x` and `y = -x` because `sin(x)` varies from `-1` to `1`.  It has no y asymptote.  It will look like a sin wave that continues to have higher and higher amplitude (infinitely high as x goes to infinity).

Comment: The good news is that if you manage to find a solution to your problem you'll become the world's most famous mathematician overnight.

Comment: Ok... So assuming there's no real solution to that problem, what's at least  the best one that could be implemented? Calculating of mentioned asymptotes?

How does WolframAlpha do that then? [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+to+infinity+of+sin%28x%29*x)

Comment: There are entire math courses on techniques for calculating limits as x --> infinity for an arbitrary equation and many pieces of it are covered in other courses such as calculus.  WolframAlpha has taken enormous amounts of math knowledge and turned it into code - essentially trying to do what a very smart math brain can do.  It is very, very impressive what they have done and completely proprietary and not something you can just download and put in your own app yourself.

Comment: You are leaving the territory of graph plotters and entering the realm of CAS here. Are you sure you want to proceed?

Comment: I am looking for a solution because I have to as it's a school project. So at least I should implement "the best available solution" even it won't be always correct.

Answer (score 0):

You may try sympy in python. [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/tutorial.html#limits)

Essentially it supports limit function, and based on the output, you can know whether a function goes to infinity or not as the variable approaches to some value.

```
>>> limit(sin(x)*x, x, oo)
∞sin(∞)

>>> limit(1/x, x, oo)
0

>>> limit(x**x, x, 0)
1
```

Comment: Was trying to understand how [sympy's **limits.py**](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/008fe0bc142b9851deeb606a61e2a5df83b9fe47/sympy/series/limits.py) works. Head exploded.